# Detecting ground with Atmel/Arduino and waking up from sleep

Tags: batteries, ground, atmel

I'm building a small board which should start working when it is touching ground.
I want the battery to last (without a physical switch) so I put the board to sleep. However I would like to wake up the Atmel processor when it is touching ground.

I made the following sketch, but as I'm unfortunately a electronics newb, there's bound to be faults with this sketch/logic.

Would it leak a lot of battery current for example? Does it work like this at all?

[image: My 5 year old drawing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram would work but since battery power saving is a concern, there's probably a more effective way to do this. However my way won't put the atmel to sleep, but rather turning it off and on completely.

You should have a battery and make an open circuit between the negative of the battery and after the load, then put the two wires exposed to ground. And if the ground is made out of conductive metal, when the board is placed on the ground, the two wires will come in contact with the ground and the circuit will flow through the battery, through the load, through the wire to the ground, through ground, back into the other wire and back into the battery.

It should look like this:
[image]

You could have some soft button or pressure switch and make the board push the switch down on its own weight, but that is if your ground isn't conductive.

Comment: That is a very clever way, cool!

Comment: Follow up on the leaking current out of interest, how much would it leak minimally?

Comment: @RobotRock If you pull the board up, it's literally an open circuit, so ideally it's zero. But of course, a tinsy amount of current can go through the air. It matters on battery leakage, humidity and other factors in which I am not so familiar about.

Comment: I meant for my original idea, you said it works but would draw current continues. How much current would it draw then in best engineered case?

Comment: @RobotRock You may want to look at the datasheet for the attiny you are using. – Active Mode:
• 200μA at 1MHz and 1.8V
Idle Mode:
• 25μA at 1MHz and 1.8V
– Power-down Mode: • <0.1μA at 1.8V

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8127-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny4-ATtiny5-ATtiny9-ATtiny10_Datasheet.pdf